# Multiple fields with the same name in AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Everyone.

I got some good help a couple of days ago, so I'm hoping that someone can show me where I'm going wrong here.  Basically, what I'm trying to do is update a MySQL database in the background when a user clicks a button.  The form is a series of records, and the records have common field names (ID, DSA_Number, Manager_Review, etc.)  Right now, the code doesn't even seem to return success or failure messages.

Here's the script on the main page:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $("#button").click(function(){

                        var DDD_Number=$("#DDD_Number").val();
                        var Manager_Review=$("#Manager_Review").val();
                        var RID=$("#RID").val();
                        var Services=$("Services").val();
                        var Dues_List=$("Dues_List").val();
                        var ID=$("ID").val();
                        var myrid=$("myrid").val();
                        var Manager_Comments=$("Manager_Comments").val();
                        var President_Comments=$("President_Comments").val();
                        var dataTosend='?DDD_Number='+DDD_Number+'&Manager_Review='+Manager_Review+'&RID='+RID+'&Services='+Services+'&Dues_List='+Dues_List+'&Manager_Comments='+Manager_Comments+'&President_Comments='+President_Comments;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url:'baseupdater-test.php' + dataTosend,
                            data:dataTosend,
                            async: true,
                          success:function(data){
                                document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = "Success.";
                                document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = data;
                            },
                            error: function(data){
                               document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = "Failure.";
                           }
                        });
                    });
        </script>
```

Here's the code that draws the rows on the table:

```
<?php

/*  This code writes the rows in the table for baserecord.php */

$n = 0;
$o = $n + 1;

$firstday = date('m/1/Y');
if(isset($_GET['MR']))  // If $_GET['MR'] is set ...
{
    $MR = $_GET['MR'];  // Set the variables.
    $PR = $Pres_Rev;
}
else  // If not, select the maximum (latest) Manager Review Date.
{
    $getmr = "select max(STR_TO_DATE(Manager_Review_Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) as Manager_Review_Date, 
    President_Review_Date from clientdb.MRS2_test
    inner join clients_MRS
    on clientdb.clients_MRS.DDD_Case = clientdb.MRS2_test.DDD_Number
    where SCID = '$ID';";

    $rs2 = mysqli_query($con,$getmr);
    $rvd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2);
    $MR = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rvd['Manager_Review_Date']));
    echo "MR: $MR<br>";
    $PR = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rvd['President_Review_Date']));
}


// The following query select the data for the row and orders it by the latest Manager Review Date. 

$cliselect    = "select distinct clientdb.Plans.Client_ID, clientdb.clients_MRS.DSA_Status, clientdb.clients_MRS.DSA_Status_Date, clientdb.clients_MRS.First_Name, clients_MRS.Last_Name, clientdb.clients_MRS.County, clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case, RID, Plans.Program, max(Plans.Plan) as MPlan, Tier, Plan_End_Date, clientdb.MRS2_test.RID, clientdb.MRS2_test.President_Comments, clientdb.MRS2_test.Manager_Comments, clientdb.MRS2_test.Services_Issues, clientdb.MRS2_test.Dues_List
     from clientdb.Plans 
     inner join clientdb.clients_MRS on clientdb.clients_MRS.DDD_Case = clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case 
     inner join clientdb.MRS2_test on clientdb.MRS2_test.DDD_Number = clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case 
     where SCID = '$ID' and (DSA_Status = 'Active' OR (DSA_Status <> 'Active' AND STR_TO_DATE(DSA_Status_Date, '%d/%m/%Y') > STR_TO_DATE($firstday, '%m/%d/%Y'))) AND (Manager_Review_Date = '$MR')
     group by clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case order by STR_TO_DATE(clientdb.MRS2_test.Manager_Review_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC, clientdb.Plans.Last_Name;";

     //echo "cliselect $cliselect<br>";


    $cres         = mysqli_query($con, $cliselect);




while ($dddr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cres)) {
    $DDD_Case              = $dddr['DDD_Case'];
    $First_Name            = $dddr['First_Name'];
    $Last_Name             = $dddr['Last_Name'];
    $County                = $dddr['County'];
    $Tier                  = $dddr['Tier'];
    if($ddr['Plan_End_Date'] <> '')
        {
            $Plan_End_Date         = $dddr['Plan_End_Date'];
        }        

    $Pres_Comments         = $dddr['President_Comments'];
    $Mgr_Comments          = $dddr['Manager_Comments'];
    $Dues                  = $dddr['Dues_List'];
    $Services              = $dddr['Services_Issues'];
    $RID = $dddr['RID'];


    $mxselect              = "select max(Plan) as MPlan from clientdb.Plans where clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case = '$DDD_Case';";
    $rens                  = mysqli_query($con, $mxselect);
    $rmm                   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rens);
    $MPlan                 = $rmm['MPlan'];
    $endsel                = "select Plan_End_Date, Program from clientdb.Plans where clientdb.Plans.DDD_Case = $DDD_Case and clientdb.Plans.Plan = $MPlan;";
    $rsel                  = mysqli_query($con, $endsel);
    $end                   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsel);
    $Plan_End_Date         = $end['Plan_End_Date'];
    $Program               = $end['Program'];
//The purpose of ths quer s to get the RID for each row.

    $mrselect = "select * from MRS2_test where DDD_Number = '$DDD_Case' and Manager_Review_Date = '$MR'
                group by DDD_Number, RID
                order by RID DESC
                Limit 1 ;";



    $run = mysqli_query($con,$mrselect);

    $mrss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);




    $Manager_Review_Date   = $mrss['Manager_Review_Date'];
    $President_Review_Date = $mrss['President_Review_Date'];
    $myRID = $mrss['RID'][$n];



    echo "<tr><td>$o</td><td sorttable_customkey='$DDD_Case'><input class='ddd' type = 'text' value = '$DDD_Case' name = 'DDD_Number[]' size='6'></td><td sorttable_customkey='$Last_Name'>$First_Name $Last_Name</td><td>$County</td><td>$Program</td><td>$Tier</td><td sorttable_customkey='";
    ?>
<?php echo strtotime($Plan_End_Date);


echo "'>$Plan_End_Date</td><td><textarea class='expnd' name='Services[]'>$Services</textarea></td><td><input name='Dues_List[]'' type = 'text' value = '$Dues'></td><td><textarea class='expnd' name='Manager_Comments[]'>$Mgr_Comments</textarea></td><td><textarea class='expnd' name='President_Comments[]'>$Pres_Comments</textarea></td><td><input type='text' size='4' name = 'myrid[]' value='$RID' readonly></td><input type='hidden' name = 'manreview-orig' value='$Manager_Review_Date'></tr>";

    $n = $n++;
    $o++;
}
?>
```

And finally, this is the code that does the update:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($DB_server, $DB_user, $DB_password, $DB_database);

$Manager_Review   = $_GET['Manager_Review'];
$Old_MR = $_GET['manreview-orig'];
//echo "OLD MR: $Old_MR<br>";

if($_GET['President_Review'] == '12/31/1969')
{
    $President_Review = '';
}

if($_GET['President_Review'] <> '')
{
    $President_Review = $_GET['President_Review'];
}
else
{
    $President_Review = '';
}


$ID               = $_GET['ID'];
$Services = $_GET['Services'];


echo "New Content!<br>";

$n = 0;

while ($n <= sizeof($_GET)) {

    $ridselect = "select clientdb.MRS2_test.RID, clientdb.clients_MRS.DDD_Case, clientdb.clients_MRS.SCID from clientdb.MRS2_test
            inner join clientdb.clients_MRS
            on clientdb.clients_MRS.DDD_Case = clientdb.MRS2_test.DDD_Number 
            where Manager_Review_Date = '$Old_MR' and clientdb.clients_MRS.DDD_Case = clientdb.MRS2_test.DDD_Number
            order by RID;";
    $rsc       = mysqli_query($con, $ridselect);
    $rowrid    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsc);
    $RID       = $_GET['myrid'][$n];
  //  echo "RID: $RID<br>";
    $MDD = $_GET['RID'];
    $myrid = $_GET['myrid'][$n];
    $DDD_Case = $_GET['DDD_Number'][$n];




    $Period             = ltrim(substr($Manager_Review,0,2), "0");




    $Services           = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Services'][$n]);
    $Manager_Comments   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Manager_Comments'][$n]);
    $President_Comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['President_Comments'][$n]);
    $Dues_List          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Dues_List'][$n]);
    $DDD_Case           = $_GET['DDD_Number'][$n];

    $updater = "update clientdb.MRS2_test set clientdb.MRS2_test.Services_Issues = '$Services', 
    clientdb.MRS2_test.Manager_Comments = '$Manager_Comments', clientdb.MRS2_test.President_Comments = '$President_Comments', 
    clientdb.MRS2_test.Dues_List = '$Dues_List', Period = '$Period' where DDD_Number = '$DDD_Case' and RID = '$RID';";
echo $updater . "<br>";

        $date_updater = "update clientdb.MRS2_test set clientdb.MRS2_test.Manager_Review_Date = '$Manager_Review', 
    clientdb.MRS2_test.President_Review_Date = '$President_Review' where RID = '$RID';";
    echo "dateupdater: $date_updater<br>";
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $date_updater))
        {
          echo "That failed miserably.<br>";
        }
        else
            { 
                $rws = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
                echo "affected rows: $rws<br>";
                echo "Success.<br>";
            }



    mysqli_query($con, $updater);

    $datestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $upstamp = "update clientdb.MRS2_test set Update_Time = '$datestamp' where DDD_Case = '$DDD_Case' and RID = '$RID';";
    mysqli_query($con,$upstamp);

    $n++;
}

echo "<script language='Javascript'>document.getElementById('stuffhere').InnerHTML = '<?php echo $updater; ?>';</script>";

?>
```

I've tried serializing the form, and I haven't had any success there.  Any suggestions would be greatly welcome.  Sorry for the long post, but I'm just not sure where the error is at this point.

Comment: Have a look at the last line of your code you have written `InnerHtml` change it to `innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed that.  :)  It's still not updating correctly or displaying the messages, and I'm not sure why, but that's fixed, at least.

Comment: can you tell me that where is `stuffhere` present in your code?I mean which element has this id.

Comment: It's the last tag in the main file.  I didn't share that, because the file is pretty long.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? That's a lot of code......

Comment: I have tried setting the async to true or false.  They both work the same.  I've looked into the console, but the console isn't producing any useful information.  I've also tried alternating between GET and POST to see if that would shed any light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

```
var data= [DDD_Number,Manager_Review,RID,Services,Dues_List,ID,myrid,Manager_Comments,President_Comments];
var datatosend = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url:'baseupdater-test.php',
data:dataTosend,
async: true,
success:function(data){
document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = "Success.";
document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = data;
 },
error: function(data){
document.getElementById('stuffhere').innerHTML.text = "Failure.";
 }
});
```

---

As i can see you are trying to send the data twice, first through url and second with the ajax `data` method please fix that i think its a wrong approach to do that you should send it only once.

And moreover you must convert the data into json format to make the ajax request work
and now what's happening is as your data is not in the correct format your code must be stuck at the `data` in ajax you can see it in console the ajax request would not show you any value passing to another and that is the main reason the **Success** or **Failure** are not being show.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without json?  The data isn't in json format.

Comment: Look as you said if you want to load your data in the background you via ajax you must convert your data into json format don't worry i'll guide you for that too.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for any help you can give me, Kunal.  I appreciate it. :)

Comment: just after all your variables place this code and remove you whole line of code with var `dataTosend`

Comment: Thanks, Kunal. I've changed the code accordingly, and I'll let you know how it goes.  I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215180/discussion-between-brian-hartman-and-kunal-raut).